# MySql how COUNT(column_name = 'foobar' or null) works?

Tags: mysql, count, boolean-logic, sql-null

I want to understand how `or null` works in this example:

```
Select columnA, count(columnB = 'foobar' or null) as result 
from orders 
group by columnA
```

If I don't use `or null` then it just give the count(*) of columnB based on group by but with `or null` it gives correct count of values where `columnB = 'foobar'`

Just wondering how it works internally?

Comment: It returns 1 for rows that match foobar, and null (as opposed to 0) for rows that don't. COUNT() doesn't count nulls (but it does count 0), so it's equivalent to `SUM(columnB = 'foobar')` [or `SUM(CASE WHEN columnB = 'foobar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `columnB` is not nullable, the expression:

```
columnB = 'foobar'
```

is a boolean expression that is evaluated as `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

So by using it with `COUNT()` here:

```
count(columnB = 'foobar')
```

it is equivalent to `count(0)` or `count(1)` which both return the same result:

> the number of all of the rows of the table (just like `count(*)`)

because the argument of `COUNT()` is never `NULL`.

The expression:

```
columnB = 'foobar' or null
```

is also a boolean expression, but it may also be evaluated as `null` when `columnB = 'foobar'` is `false` (`false or null` is `null`, while `true or null` is `true`).

So by using it with `COUNT()` here:

```
count(columnB = 'foobar' or null)
```

it counts only the rows where `columnB = 'foobar'` is `true`, because for all the others `columnB = 'foobar' or null` is `null`.

Although your code works, I prefer to use conditional aggregation, like:

```
count(case when columnB = 'foobar' then 1 end)
```

or:

```
sum(columnB = 'foobar') -- works in MySql and SQLite
```